# Validação não funciona jquery

Tags: jquery

Colegas

Fiz esse script para validar o acesso, porém não está funcionando. Alguém sabe me informar onde está o erro?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#submit').submit(function(){
      alert('aqui');

      return false;
    });
  </script>
    <body>
<div id="success"></div>
<form  id="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
    <input name="Email" placeholder="Login" id="login" type="text" required >
    <input name="Password" placeholder="Senha" id="senha" type="password" required>
    <div class="sign-up">
      <div align="center">
          <button type="submit" value="Acessar" id="submit"/>Acessar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de colocar o `<script>` depois do HTML, pois assim o jQuery não encontra o botão uma vez que o seu HTML ainda não foi lido.

Repare ainda que:

- a tua tag script que carrega o jQuery tem de ser fechada, falta o `</script>`
- o evento deve ser `click` e não `submit`. Se ao invés de `$('#submit').submit(function(){` colocares esse event handler na `form` aí sim deves usar o `submit`.

Uma alternativa é juntar uma função para correr somente quando a página tiver carregada, nesse caso seria assim:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#submit').click(function() {
        alert('aqui');
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <div id="success"></div>
  <form id="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
    <input name="Email" placeholder="Login" id="login" type="text" required>
    <input name="Password" placeholder="Senha" id="senha" type="password" required>
    <div class="sign-up">
      <div align="center">
        <button type="submit" value="Acessar" id="submit">Acessar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Coloquei depois do HTML e funcionou. Aprendendo com os erros ; ) .Obrigado mais uma vez Sérgio.